# unable to load libclang in ffi-generatefor node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-ffi

I am using node js to test one of my projects. My code is in c++ and i need to make an automate javascript wrapper from the c++ header file. I have come across ffi-generate and found that it can parse the c/c++ header file into javascript file. While trying the command mentioned here 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffi-generate

I got an error

**Unable to load libclang, make sure you have 3.2 installed, either specify -L or have llvm-config in your path.**

I have also installed LLVM 3.4 and added the path to system path. libclang.dll is present inside LLVM\lib. I have also passed the path using -L option still it fails.

It would be helpful if someone figure out how to install libclang.dylib in windows and use ffi-generate to parse c/c++ file to javascript.

Comment: Try `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/clang+llvm-3.6.0-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib`

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libclang-3.8-dev
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:"/usr/lib/llvm-3.8/lib/"
```